# How do I determine correctness of a codes complexity?

Tags: complexity

Given a piece of code, I may use one of many methods to determine the big O complexity of the code manually (runtime and memory).

But, for a given piece of code, how do I determine whether what I found earlier is correct or not? Are there tools available where I give an EXE, give test cases and I get an output saying that the runtime is O(n^2) and memory usage is O(1) for instance?

Comment: It is obvious, due to the definition of big-O, there cannot be tools which will can prove or disprove a complexity *for sure*. However, I think the question makes sense if you ask for a tool or method to check the plausibility of a certain complexity by utilizing an implementation.

Comment: ... the "tool" which you can use for this check is called [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis). Of course, you have to produce a set of samples, for example, for the running time, controlled by some "n".

Comment: @DocBrown  Thanks, are you aware of any tools\libraries to perform regression analysis against C# code\console apps?

Comment: Don't expect an out-of-the-box solution. For regression analysis, you can use, for example, MS Excel/and or R (the programming language), see here http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/education/lectures/r/regression.htm. To collect the data for that step, you will have to write some code on your own beforehand. If you prefer that, use C#, then it is pretty simple to write a helper program which starts an arbitrary command line program with a certain set of parameters and measure its run time.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are no such tools.  Google didn't find one for me.  But feel free to look again :-)

Actually, I wouldn't expect a standalone tool to either be accurate ... or generally useful.

- It is unlikely to be accurate because there are all sorts of factors in a typical application that distort the performance data that you can measure "from the outside".  For example, the behavior of a typical garbage collector.
- It is unlikely to be useful for a couple of reasons:

  - Big-O complexity measures are generally applied to specific parts of a program rather than a program as a whole.
  - For a typical program, the scaling parameters involve the size of input files.  In most cases, it is not possible for a general "complexity measurement" tool to generate meaningful input files of various sizes.
  - Finally, when we have a complete / working application, the big-O complexity is largely of academic interest.  What is really interesting is the actual *performance* measures; i.e. how much actual time and space is required to run the application for a given dataset / parameters.  Big-O complexity doesn't predict that.